# Javascript Material UI error with tab navigation/accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, material-ui, accessibility

I am working on a JS/React web app's tab navigation accessibility.  On two pages in my app, both which use the Material UI tooltip plugin, the tabbing freezes or “gets trapped” off the page after cycling through the last navigable element on the page, rather than looping back to the first item at the top.

Then, if you hit enter when it is trapped off screen, the page crashes with the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
PopupTooltipTakeover.onTakeoverCloseTouchstart
src/components/popupTooltip/popupTooltipTakeover.js:59

This looks like a bug in the tooltip plugin module itself, not in any code on the page itself.  Does it seem that way?  (It only happens on pages w/ the tooltip plugin).

If it is a bug in the tooltips, not the page, how could something like that be fixed?

Comment: what is at line 59 of the file? Can you reproduce this on a fiddle? At the moment all we can tell you is that some function somewhere is attempting to use `.querySelector` on a parent item but is being passed a null reference (as the parent item does not exist). Drop us a bit more info please, preferably an example that reproduces the problem so that we can help.

Comment: and to fix it you need to do an error check `var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);` grab the parent element.
      `if (parentElement != null) {` parent exists so we are safe `parentElement.querySelector('.someClass');};`

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), thanks